# Alloy Function with many requirement

Tags: function, alloy

```
sig Student, Tutor, Mark {} 
sig Course { 
    reg : set Student, 
    alloc : Student -> Tutor, 
    result : Student -> Mark 
   }
```

I want to be able to takes course c as input; outputs the set of tutors who are responsible for one or more students registered for c who do not yet have a mark.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time it seems your are asking about how to write set comprehensions in Alloy.  You can then use a set comprehension to write a function that for a given course returns all students who registered for that course such that they don't have a mark assigned.  After that it is easy to select tutors assigned to those students, directly from the `alloc` relation.

Syntax for set comprehensions in Alloy is the following

```
{x: expr | condition(x)}
```

and it means "*select all `x` that belong to set `expr` such that `condition(x)` holds*".

Here is how to write this for your problem:

```
sig Student, Tutor, Mark {}

sig Course {
  reg: set Student, 
  alloc: Student -> Tutor,
  result: Student -> Mark
}

fun studentsWithNoMarks[c: Course]: set Student {
  {s: c.reg | no c.result[s]}
}

fun tutorsForStudentsWithNoMarks[c: Course]: set Tutor {
  c.alloc[studentsWithNoMarks[c]]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is my first time trying alloy so it's a little bit hard